# Can store hash in a cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

Anyone know if I can put a hash in the cookie?
Something like this: cookies [: test] = {: top => 5,: middle => 3,: bottom => 1}

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I woud look into serializing the hash to store it. Then deserialize it to retrieve it.

When you serialize a hash, the result will be an encoded string. This string can be decoded to get the original object back.

You could use YAML or JSON for this. Both are nicely supported in Ruby.

---

A YAML example

```
require "yaml"

cookies[:test] = YAML::dump {a: 1, b: "2", hello: "world"}
# => "---\n:a: 1\n:b: '2'\n:hello: world\n"

YAML::load cookies[:test]
# => {a: 1, b: 2, c: "world"}
```

---

A JSON example

```
require "json"

cookies[:test] = JSON.generate {a: 1, b: "2", hello: "world"}
# => '{"a":1,"b":"2","hello":"world"}'

JSON.parse cookies[:test]
# => {"a"=>1, "b"=>"2", "hello"=>"world"}
```

**Note:** when using `JSON.parse`, the resulting object will have string-based keys

Comment: This doesn't work for me at all :( I get complaints about the ":" character (`syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'`) Any ideas why? I've tried both your YAML and JSON suggestions, but both complain of the same issue.

Comment: FWIW, I did this a little differently which worked well for me.

`cookies[:my_cookie] = { value: ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(my_object), expires: some_time }`

I pulled it back out in a similar fashion with decode. Thanks for setting me on the right path, though.

Answer (score 5):

With Rails 4.1 I had to use the parentheses like this. Without that it gave an error.

```
cookies[:test] = JSON.generate({a: 1, b: "2", hello: "world"})
```

Comment: I don't think you need the curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways which it is possible (i.e. storing a string and `eval`ing that value, SCARY!). This is a simple way.

```
cookies[:test_top]    = 5
cookies[:test_middle] = 3
cookies[:test_bottom] = 1
```

You can also convert to JSON and then parse it when loading the cookie.

Newer versions of Rails include automatically serialization using the session object.