# Unable to retrieve hash from session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, session-variables

I have a hash:

```
hash = {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

I save it in session:

```
session[:hash_map] = hash
```

When I retrieve the hash:

```
hash2 = session[:hash_map]
```

`hash2` is:

```
{:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

but `hash2[:a]` and `hash2[:b]` return `nil`. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: what return if you type `hash2.class`?

Comment: I'm expecting that to be `String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution but i dont think that is the right one if i do hash2["a"] it works instead of hash2[:a] i dont know what is the difference

Answer (score 2):

You can only store strings in the session hash unless you serialize it or deserialize it. The session store is typically cookies. You can probably use eval(hash2) to get the hash - at least with the hash you posted - if there was a lambda or something else it wouldn't work.

An idea of how to serialize is nicely detailed here:

[Can store hash in a cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056297/can-store-hash-in-a-cookie)

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem. I have found a solution but i dont think that is the right one if i do hash2["a"] it works instead of hash2[:a]
i dont know what is the difference